# Getting started with Qt and QGIS

Tags: qgis

I would like to use GIS data as input in a C++ program, to do some work around data before to pass them to the program core, then display some maps. I would like to do that with the QGIS C++ API. I'm working in Linux 14.04 LTS.

I'm trying to make this ["hello world" example](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS-Code-Examples/blob/master/1_hello_world_qgis_style/main.cpp) work:

```c++
//
// QGIS Includes
//
#include <qgsapplication.h>
#include <qgsproviderregistry.h>
#include <qgssinglesymbolrenderer.h>
#include <qgsmaplayerregistry.h>
#include <qgsvectorlayer.h>
#include <qgsmapcanvas.h>
//
// Qt Includes
//
#include <QString>
#include <QApplication>
#include <QWidget>

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
 // Some stuff
 return app.exec();
}
```

I get an error :

```
error: qgsapplication.h: No such file or directory
```

How do I precise to Qt to find the files ? Do I need to download QGIS sources before ?

Comment: You need to install the appropriate *-dev packages (for Qt and QGIS), and you'll likely need to tell the compiler chain to include those files when searching for includes (such as in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9730952/qt-creator-build-project-no-such-file-or-directory)). In general, questions about how to install those packages and how to configure the compiler chain belong more on [SO].